# adding spring security on netbeans

Tags: spring-security

I created my project on netbeans and checked spring mvc framework and hibernate.

This created a web.xml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

However, whenever I add

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

I'm able to deploy it on tomcat but not able to run it :(
I get this error:

```
FAIL - Deployed application at context path /project but context failed to start
          <nbdeploy clientUrlPart="${client.urlPart}" debugmode="false" forceRedeploy="${forceRedeploy}"/>
```

Anyone has suggestions to fix it?

Comment: It is probably because of permission issues with tomcat. Check the Netbeans forum: http://forums.netbeans.org/ntopic42543.html. If not, there is some error in your web.xml. Can you paste the tomcat log?

Comment: This was my error:

FAIL - Deployed application at context path /ossMgr but context failed to start
C:\Development\main\application\test3\project\nbproject\build-impl.xml:736: The module has not been deployed.

So I don't think the problem is with tomcat..Do i need to add anything else whenever  I add spring security into my web.xml?